# How to get unique values in select list in interactive grid in APEX 20.1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to disable opportunity to choose the same option from select list in interactive grid.
For example we have LOV with values "1,2,3".

And we have IG with column that is select list with that LOV.
In firt row I select 1, so in second row I can only choose 2 or 3.

I'm trying for example make a DA that after all changes insert into item values that are choosen and LOV have where that check if value are in this item. This solution make problems when you're trying to change selected item.

If there is a chance to disable changing selected option it will be great!

Thx for advice

Answer (score 1):

To disable already selected options (except the default "Select") from other selects you can do the following: Select all selected options, iterate through all select fields and remove the attribute "disabled" from every option, then iterate through all selected options and set this option to "disabled" for all selects except the select field that has this value as selected option.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  let selected = $("select option:selected");
  let selects = $("select");
  selects.each(function() {
    let that = $(this);
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    selected.each(function() {
      if (that.val() !== $(this).val() && $(this).val() !== "0") {
        that.find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled", true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```